# React Native : Unexpected token, expected ","

Tags: react-native, jsx

I am a learning react native and trying to apply an if condition based on map value but getting error

[image]

```
render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>My List view</Text>
                {
                    this.state.fruits.map((item) => (

                        { if(item.id % 2 == 0) {
                        console.log("Even Number")
                    }}

                <Text key={item.id}>
                    {item.id + ". " + item.name}
                </Text>
                    ))
                }

            </View>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to start your map with brackets {
- remember to add a return statement when you want to output anything in your map loop
- seems like there were a stray bracket }

result:

```js
{fruits.map((item) => {
  if (item.id % 2 == 0) {
    console.log('Even Number');
  }

  return <Text key={item.id}>{item.id + '. ' + item.name}</Text>;
})}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are doing here

```
{
     this.state.fruits.map((item) => (
     { if(item.id % 2 == 0) {
     console.log("Even Number")
}}
```

But this looks so wrong.

This

```
.map((item) => (
```

means you are returning something and I don't **think** you can have `if-else` directly in return statement.

I think what you meant to do is

```
{
     this.state.fruits.map((item) => {
     if(item.id % 2 == 0) {
     console.log("Even Number")
     } 
     return 
    // whatever you want to return 
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>My List view</Text>
                {
                    this.state.fruits.map((item) => {

                        if(item.id % 2 == 0) {

                           console.log("Even Number")

                        }

                        return( <Text key={item.id}>{item.id + ". " + item.name </Text> )
                    
                    })
                }

            </View>
        )
    }
```